# Custom Setting GetInstance method returns null

Tags: apex, customsetting

I am currently having an issue with my custom settings returning null values when they *should*, to the best of my knowledge, return a value.

**The following code in Anonymous Apex:**

```
System.Debug(LoggingLevel.Info, [SELECT Name, Id FROM Country__c WHERE Name = 'United States of America']);
System.Debug(LoggingLevel.Info, Country__c.getValues('United States of America'));
```

**Clarification on the Debug Statements**

I used SOQL within my debug statement to query for the custom setting the first time to only verify that:

- I actually had a custom setting of that name.
- It could be searched by the `Name` field - just like a `GetInstance` or `GetValues` methods would.

The results I got back clarify that searching by the name value within SQOL will get the correct custom setting information. However, my `GetInstance` and `GetValues` method returns `null`.

**Both return different results *(when they shouldn't)*:**

```
14:25:24.053 (53689000)|USER_DEBUG|[1]|INFO|(Country__c:{Name=United States of America, Id=a01a000000anByPAAU})
14:25:24.054 (54989000)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|INFO|null
```

Am I missing something? I was always under the impression that both should work the same.

**Other Information**

I used the SOQL statement to verify that the custom setting exists and can be queried for by the Name - what you use to retrieve instances of a custom setting.

I have even tried using GetInstance:

```
System.Debug(LoggingLevel.Info, Country__c.getInstance('United States of America'));
```

But the same result occured - the `GetInstance` method returned null.

**Edit: Further Investigation**

Upon suggestion by @eyescream, I used the `getAll` method to retrieve my custom setting. If the `getInstance` and `getValues` didn't return what I wanted, `getAll` wouldn't either, right?

**So I updated my Anonymous Apex to the following:**

```
System.Debug(LoggingLevel.Info, [SELECT Name, Id FROM Country__c WHERE Name = 'United States of America']);
System.Debug(LoggingLevel.Info, Country__c.getInstance('United States of America'));

for(Country__c SingleCountry : Country__c.getAll().values())
    if(SingleCountry.Name == 'United States of America')
        System.Debug(LoggingLevel.Info, String.valueOf(SingleCountry));
```

**The Intriguing Results**

```
13:56:06.048 (48182000)|USER_DEBUG|[1]|INFO|(Country__c:{Name=United States of America, Id=a01a000000anByPAAU})
13:56:06.049 (49151000)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|INFO|null
13:56:06.060 (60227000)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|INFO|Country__c:{Name=United States of America, SetupOwnerId=00De0000002LT3WEAW, Country_Name__c=United States of America, LastModifiedById=00530000006MGQeAAO, SystemModstamp=2012-10-24 05:48:36, CreatedById=00530000006LZDrAAO, CreatedDate=2012-10-15 22:50:34, LastModifiedDate=2012-10-24 05:48:36, IsDeleted=false, Id=a01a000000anByPAAU, Code__c=US}
```

Comment: Is this a list C/S or Hierarchy? I tried that code for a list C/S and it worked as you are expecting (i.e. getvalues() returns the same result)

Comment: If you goto custom settings and click manage by the appropriate setting, is there actually a record with the name of 'United States of America'?

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC - It is a custom settings list.

Comment: @Eric - The reason I did the SOQL query using the Name field in the WHERE clause was to verify that a record with 'United States of America' existed.

Comment: Interesting! And what does `Country__c.getAll()` return?

Comment: @eyescream - I added a section with updated code showing the results of that. Quite surprising. Now it makes sense why some of my other code operates normally and others does not.

Comment: Weird. Inconsistent fetching from cache sounds like a huge screw-up ;) So it seems the long awaited [copying of custom settings to dev sandboxes](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HJ3pAAG) "delivered" in Summer'13 is still completely unreliable. Check https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SzhCAAS too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this in a sandbox post-refresh? If so, there is (or was maybe fixed by now) a bug that caused exactly what you're seeing. The only fix was to recreate the records in the custom settings.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I will check to see if that is the problem later on during the day.

Comment: That was it! Quite a fickle bug, eh?

Comment: Quite! Gotta love sandbox refresh quirks.

Answer (score -3):

You do not use SQL to retrieve custom settings. You use the Static methods for the custom settings object to retrieve the values: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm.

The code you are looking for is

```
Country__c ctry = Country__c.getValues('United States of America');
```

The getValues Method return the record with the Name value equal to the text passed into the method
Then to access the fields for that record simply use regular dot notation.

i.e.

```
Custom Setting API Name: Country__c

Custom Setting Field Name: State__c ('Ohio')

Custom Setting Field Name: Name ('United States of America')

Country__c ctry = Country__c.getValues('United States of America');

system.debug(ctry.State__c); //Should be 'Ohio'
```

Comment: It's not that you don't use SOQL - the point is you don't HAVE to use SOQL to retrieve a custom setting - you can use the static methods to avoid a SOQL statement because they are cached. But if you want to order your results based on on a field on the C/S, it can be easier to query, rather than retrieve and sort the data yourself...

Comment: Correct. You can use SQL but no need.

Comment: I added further clarification on the problem I am having.  The issue I am dealing with is that the `GetInstance` method is returning `null` despite proof that the custom setting not only exists but, can be queried by the Name field used by the `GetInstance method`. The SOQL query I used in the debug statement was just used to show that the custom setting was actually visible.